# What might have turned dupliverts off?

Tags: dupli-groups

I have a file with a duplivert system on part of it, which was working fine, and then something caused it to disappear. Nothing I do to fix it or rebuild it works, in fact, after testing, nothing made with dupliverts is working. For kicks I built a simple duplivert setup in a new file just to make sure that yes I am doing it right. That worked. The one in the file I'm working on still doesn't. Not the one I built originally or the test object systems.

What could turn that off?

[image]

There's the file, stripped down to just those objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have no idea what is going on, but I played with your blend file and got it to work again. It must be some kind of bug.

1. Collapse your windows on the left like I did
2. Then Collapse your side window with your main 3D window
3. Click the bottom window pane to get back to your 3D view
4. Notice it changes what layer you are on at the bottom
5. Click back to the 2nd layer with your object on it
6. And all of a sudden dupliverts started working again.

WEIRD!!

[image]

Comment: Wow. So, i guess that means it is something a bit glitchy with display

Comment: In the interest of science, i returned to the original and got it to render (after adding a camera and a new lamp), and it wasn't rendering anything. Once i followed these instructions again, it rendered everything normally. Hm. Anyhow, thanks a lot, and i have no idea how you managed to come across that.

Comment: lol me either, I was just resetting the windows to how I usually have them to start trouble shooting and noticed it was switching layers when I did that. Glad it helped.